# Objective-C: Facebook username from link returned by Graph API call

Tags: iphone, objective-c, facebook, ios4, nsstring

Fetching http://graph.facebook.com/514417 from the Facebook Graph API gives me the `NSString @"http://www.facebook.com/mattdipasquale"`. How do I extract just `mattdipasquale` every time? Can I assume the link will be the same format every time? In that case, I could just do:

```
NSString *fbUsername = [[result valueForKey:@"link"] substringFromIndex:24];
```

That works, but it seems kinda brittle. Do you recommend a better way?

Thanks!

Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *fbUsername = [[result valueForKey:@"link"] lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: Thanks! That's exactly what I wanted. You're pretty damn smart!

Comment: What? You are asking a question and answering it yourself (that's fine) and then you compliment yourself as well

Answer (score 1):

Using fb api for iOS should be easier

```
  NSMutableDictionary * params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                  @"SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid=<your user id>", @"query",
                                  nil];
  [_facebook requestWithMethodName: @"fql.query" 
                         andParams: params
                     andHttpMethod: @"POST" 
                       andDelegate: self];
```

Should get you formal name.

Comment: What you give is FQL, and what is in the question is Graph API. They are different kinds of API of FB

Comment: That's true, just to give another option that i get as easier, at least for getting user public data.

Comment: Yes, I'm using `facebook-ios-sdk`, except I'm doing: `[fb requestWithGraphPath:@"me" andDelegate:self];` because I also want other data. Anyway, that call returns the `link: "http://www.facebook.com/mattdipasquale"` data. Is this more efficient than fql? I figured they`d optimize it since it's a common request. Thanks for your answer though because it may come in handy if I want to do more customized requests in the future.